# Outer shell electrons

Tags: physical-chemistry

I'm trying to find the answers for how many free outer shell electrons that are present in Nickel chloride, I know that nickel has 2 outer shell electrons and chlorine 7.

But nickel chloride is made from one unit nickel and 2 units of chlorine, I am trying to work out how much of an increase is likely to occur in what is called Compton scatter, as this is dependant on the amount of free outer shell electrons (valence)

Quote "In Compton scattering, a photon interacts with a weakly bound outer shell electron. Instead of being completely absorbed as in the photoelectric interaction, in the Compton process the photon is deflected from its original direction and continues to exist but at lower energy"

So needing total unattached/weakly bound electrons in NiCl² please

Comment: You have mixed up all possible concepts, I am not sure what are you trying to ask.

Comment: Edited question, hopefully clearer?

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you will not as vague as to what possible concepts were all mixed up and as such a bit more informative

Answer (score 1):

Nickel has indeed 2 electrons in the outer shell, but 10 valence electrons, as it is in the 10th Group of the Periodic Table. Its next lower shell has a similar energy level as its outer shell, so that there is a chemical interaction possible with all 8 electrons of that next shell.

Nickel(II)-chloride or NiCl2 is an ionic compound in which the 2 outermost electrons of the Nickel got transferred to the Chlorine atoms, leaving Nickel as well as Chlorine with a complete shell, the cheapest energetic state that can be reached in regular interaction those molecules. As the compound consists of ions which repel and attract each other, a crystal lattice is formed. In this lattice, the net force acting on each individual ion is the lowest possible.

As far as I am familiar with the Compton effect, I would say that it is not important in what kind of bond the electrons participate in, but how high the electron density in the matter is.

Unfortunately, I have no idea what you mean with increase. What part is increasing?

So in short, nickel(II) ions do have 8 outer shell electrons and chloride ions do, too.

Comment: I know studies have shown nickel chloride to have greater refraction of X-rays, than copper and I was wondering whether that the production of nickel chloride from cupronickel would actually increase the likelihood of Compton scatter, as it is my understanding this is dependant on the outer shell electrons that are unattached?